# How to create a collider with a physic friction for a racing track in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I will briefly explain the problem.
I am developing a racing game and I wanted to know how to add some friction to my track.
I tried to add a terrain collider with a physics material to the track mesh but it doesn't work.
I am also very confused about how to add a collider to the track that respects its shape.

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `MeshCollider` component and add it to the track, this will form a collider around your complete mesh.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MeshCollider.html

You could then apply a PhysicMaterial component to the track or your car(s) (you can add it to the collider). I believe a rigidbody component should also be added to the car, so that it can move with physics.

Mess with the values and read the docs:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html

Comment: Thank you very much

I saw in the mesh collider documentation that with the sharedMaterial property I can add a physics material to the collider otherwise by default I can't do it.

Comment: If this answers the question then mark it so if you could. Otherwise, explain what you're lacking so a better answer can be formulated and accepted.